# Stored Laravel Blade syntax in DB not parsing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am storing the URI / URL and other routes in my Links datatable.

## Example of a Link I am inserting.

```
        DB::table('links')->insert(
            [
                'group_id'          => $id,
                'title'             => 'Manage Pages',
                'type'              => 'uri',
                'url'               => '/',
                'uri'               => "{{ route('pages.admin-index') }}",
                'order'             => 0,
            ]);
```

As you can see I am storing the Blade syntax of the route() so when I pull the info from the database it will always use the update URL as I originally was directly adding the route.

### Before

```
'uri' => route('pages.admin-index'),
```

### After

```
'uri' => "{{ route('pages.admin-index') }}",
```

### The problem

When I pull the data from the database and render it on screen I do not get the parsed route, I see the explicit

`<a href="{{%20route('pages.admin-index')%20}}%20"`...  text

## My View file

```
<a href="{{ $link->uri }}">
```

### How I retrieve from the DB

```
$navs = Groups::where('published',true)->get();
```

Comment: your database 'string' isn't going to get parsed as blade that isn't how this stuff works ... the blade engine goes in and parses your blade file to regular PHP ... the (view) is now just a PHP file that gets executed like normally ... so you now just have a `<?php echo $your->database->value; ?>` it doesn't `eval` your code, blade doesn't even exist at this point   ... you would have to some how get this string and manually pass it through a blade parser, then execute the PHP code it gives you

Comment: When you see `%20` it represents a space in an encoded URL, for example, http://www.example.com/products%20and%20services.html

Comment: @lagbox - ok that make sense. When I retrieve the data using a model, can I parse the value forexample ```foreach x as y { y->link = parse(y->link)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to store the route name instead of your `uri`:

```php
DB::table('links')->insert([
    //...
    //'uri'               => "{{ route('pages.admin-index') }}",
    'route'               => "pages.admin-index",
]);
```

And on your view:

```php
<a href="{{ route($link->route) }}">
```

But if you insist to store a PHP code on DB like that, you may use `eval` PHP function:

```php
DB::table('links')->insert([
    //...
    'uri'               => "route('pages.admin-index')",
]);
```

```php
<a href="{{ eval($link->uri) }}">
```

Comment: Great answer, I was thinking of something similar, I used the type field  and a select in blade to determine the output   ```'type'  => 'route', 'url'  => 'settings.modules',```

@switch ( $link->type) 
@case(...
<a href="{{ route($link->route) }}">